# Google Container Registry in "Always Free" tier (i.e. using a Regional GS bucket)

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I'm trying to determine if Google Container Registry (GCR) can be used within the Always Free GCP tier. This tier offers free 5GB of regional storage in Google Cloud Storage (GCS). Multi-regional storage buckets are not included in the free tier.

GCR pricing is equal to the pricing of the storage used by the images. [The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/pricing#storage) says:

> The default Cloud Storage class used for most Container Registry storage buckets is called Multi-Regional.

and:

> To learn more about regional locations and their Cloud Storage classes, see [Bucket Locations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-locations). You can also [change the bucket's class](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/changing-default-storage-class).

Both links lead to the documentation for Google Storage, not specifically for Google Container Registry. I tried to follow the instructions to change the default bucket class, but the "Regional" option is disabled.

I also tried changing the GCR domain in the image tag, with the following results:

- `gcr.io`: Creates a Multi Regional bucket, unable to change to Regional
- `us.gcr.io`: Same as `gcr.io`
- `us-east1.gcr.io`: Fails with message `Invalid host name us-east1.gcr.io.`

I understand that in the past, it was possible to "bring your own bucket" to GCR, [but that seems no longer possible](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/support/deprecation-notices#non-standard_product_name_buckets).

With that all said, is it possible at all to use GCR within the Always Free tier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google cloud bucket storage class can currently not be changed from `REGIONAL` to `MULTI_REGIONAL` and vice-versa. This is the case *even* from command line via `gsutil`.

Moreover, an object's storage class cannot be `REGIONAL` if the bucket is multi-regional, and vice-versa. However, `COLDLINE` and `NEARLINE` storage classes can be used on objects within regional and multi-regional buckets.

You can only change the storage class of an object via `gsutil rewrite -s NEW_CLASS` (but a bucket's storage class can be changed from either gsutil or console).

So, you should be able to create a bucket with REGIONAL class and specify it as a GCR store.

Comment: Regarding specifying a bucket I created myself as a GCR store, it [does not seem to be possible anymore](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/support/deprecation-notices#non-standard_product_name_buckets). Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, this is because Docker Registry v1 API was deprecated and v2 has a different format. You can only use the private registry names listed in the docs.
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#choosing_a_registry_name

Comment: The documentation on the [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing) is misleading. "Cloud Run charges you only for the resources you use, rounded up to the nearest 100 millisecond. Note that each of these resources have free quota." Not entirely true. I submitted feedback for this page.